# Prove that the equation $1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{x^n}{n!}$ cannot have a multiple root.

Tags: polynomials, roots

> Prove that the equation $$1+x+\dfrac{x^2}{2!}+\cdots+\dfrac{x^n}{n!}$$cannot have a multiple root.

Using induction and the result that $f(x)=0$ have a root $\alpha$ of multiplicity $r\implies f'(x)=0$ has the root $\alpha$ with multiplicity $r-1,$ I proved that the equation can't have a multiple root of order $\ge3.$

Please help me to solve for $n=2$

Answer (score 20):

$$f(x)=1+x+\dots +\frac{x^n}{n!}$$ so $$f'(x)=f(x)-\frac{x^n}{n!}$$ Suppose $r$ is a multiple root. As you said, then $f'(r)=0$. But $$f'(r)=f(r)-\frac{r^n}{n!}=-\frac{r^n}{n!}=0$$ So we must have $$r=0$$ which is impossible as $$f(0)=1\ne 0$$

Comment: Very straightforward and clean!